# locate an element in current view

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

When I use the method `WebElement#findElement(By)` with `By.cssSelector`, it searches for the element through the whole page. But I want to restrict the selection by current-view-only. I don't want to allow Selenium to "use scrollbar". How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm really interested in a use-case for this since writing a different CSS selector / XPath expression is so easier...

Answer (score 1):

The way to go for this could be in the way of getting all the elements on the page and then filtering out those out of viewport.

[`WebElement.getLocation()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation%28%29) is a ground tool for this.

If you're in the left-top corner of the page (default after the load), you can use [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerHeight) and [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth) (most browsers, but IE9+).

```
// assuming JS is enabled for this instance of driver
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

int viewportWidth = (Integer)js.executeScript("return window.innerWidth;");
int viewportHeight = (Integer)js.executeScript("return window.innerHeight;");

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("whatever"));
for (Iterator<WebElement> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    WebElement elem = iter.next();
    Point p = elem.getLocation();
    if ((p.getX() > viewportWidth) || (p.getY() > viewportHeight)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

If you cannot say for sure that the viewport will be in its default position (at coordinates [0, 0]), you can add [`window.mozInnerScreenX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozInnerScreenX) and [`window.mozInnerScreenY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozInnerScreenY) (Firefox 3.6+ required) to the condition. Or, possibly better, [`window.scrollX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollX) and [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollY).

You also have to define whether to include partially shown elements or not and adjust the algorithm accordingly ([`WebElement.getSize()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize%28%29) to the rescue!).

If you'll have trouble that after the search, the viewport changed, try to scrool back to the original position via [`window.scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scroll).